# How can I extend the date of a client certificate after the expiration date of the root certificate?

Tags: azure, client-certificates, azure-vpn

As a result of generating and using Azure connection certificates, according to the instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site#clientcert, we obtain a self-signed root certificate and a client certificate.
If I have a root certificate that expires on 10/10/2022. If I generate a client certificate with an expiration date of 10/10/2023, that is, one year older than the root.
Query. Can I expect the VPN connection using the client certificate to continue working after 10/10/2022?

Best Regards,
Marcelo.

Comment: As a general rule, no; something doing chain validity will reject the certificate outright for having a validity period that is not bounded by its "parent".  But that's an ignorable error code in many chain engines, so this is a specific technology question... which I can't answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would not work.

Generally, you will not even be able to upload the root certificate if it's expired to a VPN gateway.

With that said, in case the root certificate expires post uploading to the Gateway, the remote clients will throw and error stating RootCertificate validity expired.
[image]